# Replace a series of logical OR operators with a for loop

Tags: javascript

I have an array called selectedTagArray. It contains a series of strings, 'zero, 'one', 'two', 'three'. When a button is clicked with a class ".navitem", a function is initiated. When this function is innitiated it checks to see if a span with class ".tags" contents includes any terms that match one or more items in the array. If a spans contents does contain a string found in the array the function returns true, if it doesn't the function returns false.

Because the array could be arbitrarily long, and there isn't a way to know how long the array would be it doesn't make sense to write a bunch of logical OR operators.

How would I convert my code to include a for loop that simply loops through the array substituting the index position instead of having to write out multiple lines of the same code?

```
<span class="tags">zero</span> // True
<span class="tags">one, three</span> // True
<span class="tags">two, four</span> // True
<span class="tags">four</span> // False



var selectedTagArray = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];

$(".navitem").click(function() {

  featureList.filter(function(item) { 

    if (
        (item.values().tags.includes(selectedTagArray[0])) ||
        (item.values().tags.includes(selectedTagArray[1])) ||
        (item.values().tags.includes(selectedTagArray[2])) ||
        (item.values().tags.includes(selectedTagArray[3]))
       ) 
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 1):

You would want something like this:

```
selectedTagArray.forEach((tag) => {
    if (item.values().tags.includes(tag) {
        return true;
    }
});
return false;
```

If one of the selected tags is found, this loop will return early. If none of the tags are found, then we will simply return false. This is a nice design because it will now allow you to simply modify the selectedTagArray rather than having to updated your 'or' logic.

Comment: `Array.prototype.some` would actually be better suited for this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should work:

```
function(item) { 
for(i = 0;i<selectedTagArray.length;i++){ 
    if(item.values().tags.includes(selectedTagArray[i])){
       return true;
    }
  }
 return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to work. I've tried something similar before while trying to solve it on my own. I believe this issue is that on every loop the function re-evaluates whether the span contains the next string. If the span contained the string on the first loop but doesn't contain the second string on the second loop, the first return of true for the span is simply replaced with a return of false on the second loop. Thus only the last value on the array is accounted for unlike a series of OR operators.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using **Array.from**

```js
$(function(){
    $("#check").click(function(){
        var selectedTagArray = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];
        var val = Array.from($(".tags"), (el,i) => $(el).text().includes(selectedTagArray[i]));
        console.log(val);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="tags">zero</span><br/>
<span class="tags">one, three</span><br/>
<span class="tags">two, four</span><br/>
<span class="tags">four</span><br/>

<button id="check">Click</button>
```